# How many devices an internal tester can install an app using testflight via iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I am trying internal iTunes connect testflight to make beta testing for an app but I need to know if I am an internal tester, in how many devices I can install the beta app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

> **Internal Testers**
>
> Get feedback quickly by sharing your beta builds with up to 25 members
>   of your team who have been assigned the Technical or Admin role in
>   iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to 10 devices.

Comment: Yesterday one of our internal tester exceeded limit (11 devices) How's that possible ? Posted here in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084603/testflight-internal-tester-able-to-install-app-in-more-than-maximum-10-devices