# Testflight internal tester installed app exceeds 10 device limit

Tags: ios, testflight

Apple clearly mentioned on their page [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

"Each app can be tested by up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Developer or Admin role in iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to **10 devices**."

But surprisingly one of our internal testers invited to test 2 apps. He installed the First app in 3 devices.

> But the second app he is able to install in **11 devices**.

Can anyone please tell me what exactly limits and constraints of test flight internal tester?

Here is the **Tester Profile:**

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802883/difference-between-internal-and-external-testers-in-itunes-testflight-beta-testi) you will find your answer'

Comment: This link is expired!!

Comment: @AnuragSharma Updated link https://www.neglectedpotential.com/2014/06/testflight/ that says says 100 device limit?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by apple ->

**Installing Beta Apps**

You can install beta apps on up to 30 devices.

*See this - https://developer.apple.com/testflight/testers/*

Comment: Yeah! Now they have increased limit.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, according to Apple, you can install in up to 10 devices. I think that maybe he installed the app twice in the same device

Comment: `I think that maybe he installed the app twice in the same device` is not possible if it has same bundle id correct?